# Progress bar while fetching files from git-lfs

Tags: python-3.x, git-lfs

I'm trying to fetch files from git-lfs and show some kind of progress, but while calculating the size of the file it shows around 100 bytes(pointer size), whereas the actual size of the file is >200 mb.

```
with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
    print("Downloading %s" % file_name)
    response = requests.get(link, stream=True)
    total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')

    if total_length is None: # no content length header
        f.write(response.content)
    else:
        dl = 0
        total_length = int(total_length)
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            dl += len(data)
            f.write(data)
            done = int(50 * dl / total_length)
            sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s]" % ('=' * done, ' ' * (50-done)) )    
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is my approach.

Comment: The *Git* file size *is* just a few hundred bytes. I updated your tags, although I have no idea if the underlying file size is available anywhere.